# laravel event broadcasting between two websites

Tags: laravel-5

I have two laravel website (one for admin panel and second website). admin panel is on the same host with same database. i want to broadcast event from website and catch event from admin panel. is it available and can someone explain how to do it? thank you in advance

Comment: Hello you can use some services like https://pusher.com/ or create socket connection on your website and then using redis pubsub send some events from admin panel to website

Comment: yes i know, i'm using redis and socket.io and i wonder if its available to broadcast event from main domain and than "catch" it from subdomain?

Comment: If you use same redis for both applications it doesn't matter which domains sites have they communicate through redis

Comment: what does same redis mean?

Comment: You should use one redis instance for PubSub on website and admin panel. On web site you subscribe to some events (channels) and then from admin panel you publish some events with some channel name and data

Comment: @dyachenko what if both site servers are different ?

Comment: Hi @JdPatel 
it depends on your infrastructure, but you can have redis on one of the servers and connect to it from the second using server ip or domain instead of localhost.

Comment: Also, if you do not want to connect to redis remotely, you can add endpoint which broadcasts event to the neccessary channel and host, but the idea is the same.